# redis-server TLS Passphrase

Tags: ssl, redis, redis-server

I am using redis-server 6.0.5 with the new TLS features (Which are wonderful btw, huge shoutout to the redis developers). I am wondering if there is a standard way to pass a PEM pass phrase to the startup command (or as an ENV Variable, or as a value in redis.conf, or as a file path), given that this will be run automatically (in a kubernetes container for context).

I have tried to read input through <<EOF but 1) I have been unable to get this to work and 2) It seems like a hacky solution

Redis-server: Redis server v=6.0.5 sha=00000000:0 malloc=libc bits=64 build=576a6bc8958605f9

Command:

```
redis-server --tls-port 6379 --port 0 --tls-cert-file ./crt-file --tls-key-file ./key-file --tls-ca-cert-file ./car-crt-file <<EOF
> xxxx_my_passphrase_xxxx
> EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The only viable solution I was able to find was to decrypt the key beforehand with the passphrase. I was unable to find a way to pass the passphrase at runtime